# What is Relative and Absolute?

Tags: reference-frames, terminology, definition, relative-motion

I was studying about relative motion, and randomly thought about What actually is a Relative Term or a Absolute Term. So far in the school book it is written that, Quantities that depends on a reference frame are called relative terms, but I found this vague, and it didn't feed my curiosity.

So, I searched in internet about this, and found an article Which describe Relative and Absolute, With some Graph (Space-Time Graph I Guess I Don't remember). I don't know if its correct or not.

I am unable to Find the article again, So I thought of asking it here, as this will also benefit Others.

Comment: *I found this vague...* In what way is it vague? It’s the usual definition.

Comment: Don't overthink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Basic Meaning of Relative and Absolute**

A relative concept or a quantity is that which is defined in *relation to* something else -- in such a way that a meaningful description of the concept or the quantity necessarily involves a *reference to* the something else in relation to which it has been defined.

For example, if I told you that I have twice as many teeth as my grandma has then I have given you a relative description of the cardinality of my teeth. In other words, to meaningfully know how many teeth I have, you need to refer to how many teeth my grandma has. However, if I tell you that I have $32$ teeth then it is an absolute description of the cardinality of my teeth because it meaningfully defined in and of itself and does not need to refer to something else.

There are various slightly different meanings and contexts in which the words relative or absolute might be used in physics but the basic impulse behind the idea remains the same. I will give a couple of examples, one of which has already been mentioned in other answers:

- In a basic sense, all descriptions of quantities that have dimensionful units are necessarily relative. In particular, they convey meaningful information only in relation to their units! For example, when I tell you that my bag weighs $20 \ \mathrm{kg}$, I am telling you that its inertia is $20$ times as much as that of the famous cylinder in a bunker somewhere in France.
- A more obvious example of a relative quantity is the specific gravity of a substance. It is defined as the ratio between the density of the said substance and the density of water. As you can see, this is a relative quantity because it is defined explicitly in relation to the density of water. Notice that specific gravity is unitless but it is still a relative quantity because of the way it is defined (in other words, just because something is a pure number does not mean that it is absolute).

**Sometimes Relative Quantities Can be Promoted to the Status of Absolute**

As I discussed, a relative quantity is a quantity that is described in relation to or in reference to some other quantity. However, what if there is a *unique*/*preferred*/*natural*/*correct*/*universal*/*obvious* choice for the reference? In such a case, it might be natural to consider that whenever we speak of the relative quantity, it is understood that it is being spoken of in reference to this particular unique/preferred/natural/correct/universal/obvious reference. In this case, the relative quantity can be treated as an absolute quantity because the reference of its definition is invariable and universal. This is the reason we don't normally speak of mass being a relative quantity because the unit of mass is fixed to be $1\ \mathrm{kg}$ since the SI treaty.

**The Story of Relative and Absolute Motion**

So, what kind of a concept is motion? Well, in an obvious and basic sense, motion is a manifestly relative concept. Motion is defined as the phenomenon of an object changing its position over time *with respect to* a frame of reference. This is true both in Newtonian physics and in relativistic physics. This is obvious upon reflection because the only way to even speak of "change in position" is when you have a reference frame w.r.t. which the "change" happens. So, this is the basic definitional/conceptual sense in which all motion is trivially relative.

However! What if there were to be a uniquely preferred frame of reference? Well, in that case, it would make sense to say that we can define absolute motion as motion w.r.t. that special frame. And that is exactly what happened in Newtonian mechanics. Newton conceived of an absolute space:

> *"Absolute space, in its own nature, without regard to anything external, remains always similar and immovable. Relative space is some movable dimension or measure of the absolute spaces; which our senses determine by its position to bodies: and which is vulgarly taken for immovable space ... Absolute motion is the translation of a body from one absolute place into another: and relative motion, the translation from one relative place into another ..."*

This kind of immovable background of absolute space is very intuitive to all of us, I would presume. We kind of associate the empty space we see in the pictures or imaginations of outer space as this absolute space in which all the motion of all the planets happens. It just seems true that that is the reference frame with respect to which we ought to define *true* motion. And that's exactly what Newton did. He defined absolute motion as the motion that happens w.r.t. the frame of reference associated with this absolute space.

It should be noted that the actual equations of Newtonian mechanics were such that one cannot do any experiment to detect as to whether an object is actually moving or at rest w.r.t. this absolute space. Why? Because all the equations of motion were invariant under Galilean transformation among inertial frames. Thus, Newton's own theory predicts that an experiment that is done in the absolute rest frame, i.e., in the frame of reference that is at rest w.r.t. the absolute space and an experiment that is done in an inertial frame moving at a constant velocity w.r.t. this absolute space would both give the exact same outcome. So, all one could actually observe was relative motion. It should be noted that the more technical and deeper reason as to why Newtonian mechanics kind of needs absolute space, at a theoretical level, is to define inertial frames! Because all one can say otherwise is that an inertial frame moves at a constant velocity w.r.t. another inertial frame and we can only experimentally detect as to which frame is inertial and which frame is not (using Newton's first law). But, theoretically, one cannot explain why this set of frames all moving with mutual constant velocities is inertial but that another set of frames who are also all moving with mutual constant velocities but who are accelerated w.r.t. the first set of frames is not inertial. Absolute space solves this issue, at a theoretical level, in Newtonian mechanics.

Without going into the details of the very interesting developments in Maxwell's theory, suffice it to say that with Einstein's theories of special and general relativity, we now understand that physics does not need the notion of the absolute space (as Laplace said of God). In fact, all inertial frames are completely equivalent and thus, all motion is truly relative. Notice that this was the case all along, as I mentioned, even in Newtonian mechanics, there was no way to actually find out the supposedly preferred frame of the absolute space. Moreover, now, we don't even need the absolute space at a theoretical level to define inertial frames because, from general relativity, we know that it is gravity that defines inertial frames -- the freely falling frame is the inertial frame. And so, the verdict is that motion is indeed relative.

**Remarks**

While there is no absolute space, there are often some more natural frames of reference to work with than others. For example, in cosmology, there is a preferred frame of coordinates called the comoving coordinates -- and one speaks of the age of the universe, one is referring to the age of the universe in this specific system of coordinates. There is also a preferred frame of reference when one does special relativity on compact spaces. This allows one to define "absolute motion" as motion w.r.t. this naturally preferred coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks, all my doubts are clear. Your Explaination is what I needed...

Answer (score 2):

A relative quantity is one that is measured with respect to some standard quantity or any other particular quantity.

For example [relative density or specific gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_density) which states on this link

"*Relative density, or specific gravity, is the ratio of the density (mass of a unit volume) of a substance to the density of a given reference material. Specific gravity usually means relative density with respect to water. The term "relative density" is often preferred in scientific usage.*"

Another example is [relative atomic mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_atomic_mass) which states on this link

"*Relative atomic mass (symbol: Ar) or atomic weight is a dimensionless physical quantity defined as the ratio of the average mass of atoms of a chemical element in a given sample to the atomic mass constant. The atomic mass constant (symbol: mu) is defined as being
1/12 of the mass of a carbon-12 atom.[1][2] Since both quantities in the ratio are masses, the resulting value is dimensionless; hence the value is said to be relative.*"

You also mention motion and one of your tags is "Newtonian-Mechanics" so we'll talk about absolute and relative motion.

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_motion) page we read

"*Absolute motion is the translation of a body from one absolute place into another: and relative motion, the translation from one relative place into another ... These notions imply that absolute space and time do not depend upon physical events, but are a backdrop or stage setting within which physical phenomena occur.*"

Relative motion is motion that is observed from one reference frame or to some other system which constitutes a frame of reference. In other words, the motion of one object with respect to another object which is considered "fixed". For example, if we have to objects A and B that are in motion relative to one another, their relative velocity is $$v_r = v_B-v_A$$

Answer (score 1):

Dependence on the reference frame can be restated in less precise language as dependence on the point of view. So relative quantities are those that depend on the point of view of the physicist who is talking about them, while absolute quantities will be the same for all physicists. Does this formulation satisfy you more?

But note, this formulation is the vague one. The one you provided is precise.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first present two examples.

The Kelvin scale of temperature uses the absolute zero temperature point as its zero point. In the lab of a standards institute there are machines for calibrating thermometers. These machines must themselves be calibrated too, of course. The procedure involves a series of measurements that allow extrapolation so that the point of absolute zero temperature can be inferred with certainty. That is how the zero point of the Kelvin temperature scale is an absolute zero point.

When you want to assign a coordinate system to the surface of a sphere the choice of zero point of the coordinate system is arbitrary. In the case of the Earth we have the Earth rotation, so it's natural to set the equator as zero point of latitude. The choice of *zero point of longitude* is arbitrary. The meridian of Greenwich is used because it so happens that when the time was there to establish a global convention of longitude coordinates Britain was the dominant sea-fairing nation.

The point of zero temperature is an absolute because it can be reproduced independently. In every laboratory where a procedure is used to infer where the zero point of temperature is the procedure will arrive at the same zero point.

The demarcation is whether or not the choice of zero point is *arbitrary*.

The choice of zero point of position is arbitrary, making position a relative quantity

The choice of zero point of velocity is arbitrary, making velocity a relative quantity.

Orientation:
Choice of zero point of orientation is arbitrary

Angular velocity:
Independent procedures will arrive at *the same* zero point of angular velocity.
Examples of application in engineering:
The Apollo Moon missions used mechanical gyroscopes to keep track of change of orientation of the spacecraft during propulsion.
Today's spacecrafts and aircrafts have onboard devices that  do angular velocity sensing using *light*. These devices perform the same function as mechanical gyroscopes, so they are being referred to as 'gyroscopes' but the operating principle does not require moving (mechanical) parts. There are Fiber Optic Gyroscopes and Ring Laser Gyroscopes.

Acceleration:
Independent procedures will arrive at *the same* zero point of acceleration.

However, in the case of acceleration there is a subtlety:
Inertial mass and gravitational mass are equivalent.

A numerical model for global Earth weather will use the center of mass of the Earth as zero point of all motion, because for the motion of air mass in the atmosphere the Earth's gravity is the dominant influence.

A numerical model for the motion of all the bodies of the solar system will use the center of mass of the Solar system as zero point of all motion.

A numerical model for the motion of the stars of the Galaxy will use the center of mass of the Galaxy as zero point of all motion.

While being aware of the above: choice of zero point of acceleration is clearly not arbitrary.